# how to configure email for shell script?

Tags: shell, sqoop

I want to send sqoop job log to my mail id,I am running sqoop jobs in shell script.
And I want to add some message in body of the mail and I need to send this to multiple email ids

Comment: Voting to close as **Too broad** : "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question."  Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,    https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: The question sounds too broad as @shellter mentioned in the above comment, I would suggest you add what you tried and where you are facing the issues and so on, please go through the above links from shellter. because I understand you are new and by hoping your next question will be well formatted I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect your sqoop job log to a file and attach it in the email, below is the code for it, please read the comments with # to understand what it is doing.

```
#!bin/bash
 set -x

#Parameters used below
EMAIL_MESSAGE="Someemail message the you want to send"
#Something like SqoopJob@localhost.com from address before @
FROM_ADDRRESS="SqoopJob" 
SUBJECT="email subject"
#Your directory path to save the file
TEMP_DIR="/some/path/"
CC="user1@gmail.com"
TO"user2@yahoo.com"

#redirect your sqoop job log to a file #Something like below

sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/db --username root --table employee --m 1 >> ${TEMP_DIR}/SqoopLogFileTosend.txt

#Sending email with attachment

echo -e "${EMAIL_MESSAGE}" | mailx -r "${FROM_ADDRRESS}" -s "${SUBJECT}" -a ${TEMP_DIR}/SqoopLogFileTosend.txt -c ${CC} -- ${TO}
```